# Cannot handle a form in php

Tags: php

I'm learning now php and i'm stuck in one place with handling form submit action.
Im my input i'm trying to store user name in `$_GET['firstname']` variable. But it's empty. I mean, that after checking if `$_GET['firstname']` isset I get false. Where is my mistake?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section back">
            <form class="form myform" action="addcustomer.php" method="get">
                <span class="myformtitle">
                    Add new User
                </span>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col validate-input">
                        <span class="label-input">Firstname</span>
                        <input id="firstname" class="input myinput" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your firstname" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['firstname'])) echo $_GET['firstname']?>">
                        <span class="focus-input"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-btn">
                    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn sb-btn btn-block">
                        <span class="btn-sp">
                            Submit
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['firstname'])) {
        echo '<script>console.log("' . $_GET['firstname'] . '")</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script>console.log("no name")</script>';
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: `<button type="button"` >>> `<button type="submit"`

Answer (score 3):

Change your button type from `button` to `submit`.

- `button` types are for Javascript (JS).
- `submit` types are used to process PHP (form) directives.